# how can i do a hitest with 2 classes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5

how can i make a hitest with 2 classes 1 class is called enemy and the second is called player
they both are movieclip classes and the movieclips have instances of 
the enemy class movieclip = Enemy
and the player class movieclip = Player

can you give me the code please ive been stuck on this 2 days now please help

thanks 
fastboy619
of the actionscript.org forum

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. Below is a link to a tutorial + an excerpt from the tutorial of the code that is specifically performing this op:

```
if (circle.hitTestObject(square)) {
     hittext.text = "Ouch!";
} else {
     hittext.text = "";
}
```

http://www.foundation-flash.com/tutorials/as3hittesting/